# Map does not display points on first click

Tags: angularjs, html, leaflet

This is my problem
This is my controller:

```
    angular.module('app')
     .controller('HomeController', HomeController)

        function HomeController($state,$http,$scope){

        var vm = this;
        var mylist, lp;

        var showPoints = function(){
            $http.get('api/map').success(function(response){ 
                 mylist= response;
                 vm.selectList = mylist;
                 $scope.vm.objectSelected = mylist[0];
                 $scope.showCordinates($scope.vm.objectSelected );
        });
        }

        showPoints();

        $scope.showCordinates = function(obj){
            $scope.vm.objectSelected =obj;
            lp = obj.mynumber;
            $http.get('api/device/'+lp).success(function(response){
                    $http.get('api/provider/'+response.devId+'/'+obj._id).success(function(response){
                   $scope.vm.objectSelected.locations = response;

}
```

This is my html code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" style="margin-left:5px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="p-t-4"><h4>Serial Number</h4></th>
            </tr>        
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-class="{selected:vm.objectSelected===obj}" ng-repeat="obj in vm.selectList | filter:search" ng-click="showCordinates(obj)"> 
                <td>{{obj.mynumber}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<map object="vm.objectSelected" > </map>
```

The expected behaviour is that if one click on serial numbers listed on the table my map has to be refreshed to display points according to the clic(at the expected position). Unfortunately this is what is happening on my app: if I click on a serial number at the first time nothing happened. I have to click first on another serial number and finally clic back again on the previous one to refresh the map and show its points.
I don't understand why that bug is happening.
My map is managed by leaflet library.

Answer (score 0):

What is your default leaflet map settings?  When I have used this, I always had to "extend" my controller with a default start point, kind of like:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('defaultmap',['$scope', '$http', 'leafletData', function($scope, $http, leafletData){

angular.extend($scope, {
    center: {
            lat: 27.4086665,
            lng: 1.7576433,
            zoom: 3
            },
    defaults: {
            scrollWheelZoom: false
            }
});

$scope.onloadMap = function() {
    $http.get('api/lib').success(function(data, status) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            geojson: {
                data: data,
                style: function(feature){
                  var myStyles = {
                    fillColor: '#5e5e5e',
                    weight: 1,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
              }
          }
      }
    }
  )}
)}
}]);
```

Comment: where the onloadMap has to be injected in my html?

Comment: You setup another HTML element like:
         <leaflet id="myMap" geojson="geojson" lf-center="center" defaults="defaults" legend="legend" width="100%" height="800px"></leaflet>

onloadMap runs on its own when controller is called.

Comment: This Angular Leaflet directive really helps:
https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive